# Не изменяется число

Tags: java, android

Не изменяется `indexElementToDelete` (всегда равен 0), даже сеттеры и геттеры применял - не помогло!
Часть кода:

```
public class FindSome extends AppCompatActivity implements  IMassive {

    private int indexElementToDelete;
    private FindSome findSome;
     ...

    public void setIndex(int i){
        this.indexElementToDelete = i;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_some);
        ...
        findSome = new FindSome();
        items.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent,
                              View view,
                              int position,
                              long id) {

                sqLiteDatabase  = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                contentValues = new ContentValues();

                Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(DBHelper.table_contacts,null,null,null,null,null,null);

                if(cursor.moveToFirst()){


                    int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.key_name);
                    int femaleIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.key_female);
                    int nameAndFemaleIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.key_femaleWithName);
                    int aboutIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.key_about);

                    do{
                        String ifresult = cursor.getString(nameAndFemaleIndex);
                        String getResult = ifresult.replaceAll(" ", "");

                        if(getResult.equals(namespers.get(position).toString().replaceAll(" ", ""))){
                            //result13.setText(namespers.get(position).toString());
                        }
                    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }

                findSome.setIndex(position);
                registerForContextMenu(items);
                dbHelper.close();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Почему** не меняется число , и **как** его изменить?

P.S. Это лишь часть кода , не весь , все методы , листенеры , записаны там где нужно.

Comment: В приведенном коде эта переменная и не меняется.

Comment: Вы точно привели нужный код в вопросе?

Comment: этот код и не изменяет значение переменной `indexElementToDelete`, с чего вы взяли, что оно должно изменяться?

Comment: Посмотрите на свой код и скажите, где в нём эта переменная вообще используется? Как воспроизвести Вашу проблему?

Comment: Я в setIndex её изменяю , это переменная - индекс ListView и String[] namespers

Comment: Так где этот метод setIndex?

Comment: Изменил вопрос , добавив методы

Comment: @pavlofff Да как не происходит this.indexElementToDelete = i;
 не меняет значение indexElementToDelete?

Comment: хорошо, тогда в каком месте класса находится строка `private int indexElementToDelete;`, это поле класса? оформите в коде структуру класса, начиная от имени класса

Comment: @pavlofff Оформил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаете пользовательский объект класса активити

```
findSome = new FindSome();
```

но активити - это системный компонент и с ним так нельзя работать. Точнее создать ее экземпляр вы можете, но это будет "мертвая" активити, которая не будет выполнять никаких возложенных на нее функций и ваш сеттер сетит "в пустоту".

Вам нужно просто вызывать метод, без указания объекта, так как это метод этого же класса:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_some);
    ...

    items.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ...

            setIndex(position);
        }
    });

}
```

создание экземпляра `findSome = new FindSome();` следует исключить из кода